# self-contained asp.net core web api is getting:- Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80131500 on Ubuntu 16.10-x64

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-1.1

I have a self contained asp.net core website, than I am able to run fine in windows 10, but when publishing for  ubuntu.16.10-x64, and running it in ubuntu 16.10 x64 desktop version is getting a:

**Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80131500**

I have run updates and upgrades of the os: 
(sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade)

I am executing the starting command as sudo.

The file has run permissions ( -rwxrwx--x )

TargetFramework is netcoreapp1.1.

libicu-dev is already the newest version (55.1-7ubuntu0.2).

How to go about troubleshooting the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 28/07/17**

While it seems there are several related issues which can cause this (most seem to be dependency related), some users have reported that for **Ubuntu 16.1** following the instructions on the [get started page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu) has resolved the error.

Several other fixes for various other scenarios are suggested on [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2018).

In addition, as per https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/11417 - some instances may be due to an existing bug in the CoreCLR 1.1 - which does not sound likely to be fixed in this version. Migrating to version 2.0 is suggested as a workaround in that case.

*Original answer:*

To help with diagnosing the issue, you can enable detailed startup errors by specifying detailed error logging with `.UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")` and `.CaptureStartupErrors(true)` as per the following example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var host = new WebHostBuilder()
      .UseKestrel()
      .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")
      .UseIISIntegration()
      .UseStartup<Startup>()
      .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
      .Build();

  host.Run();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this and also modified appsettings.json to have Debug log level for System and Microsoft, but nothing else, besides that one line, is printed to the terminal. Do I need to tail a particular file? 


  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Debug"
    }


None of the files in /var/log seems to have a recent timestamp.

Comment: I think the error will be occurring before any logging middleware is initialised - but I did find this issue, which looks extremely similar to yours - doesnt look like there is a fix https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/11417 - unless you are able to try 2.0?

Comment: @amy8374 I've updated the answer with some more options after doing a bit more digging. Sounds like a fairly non specific error message, but I'd be interested if any of these fixes work for you.

Comment: Thanks. My app is self-contained, it packs all the .net core dlls it needs. I  can't install .net core on the box. I'll update the post. Appreciate the info.

Comment: Yep, all .Net core apps should be self contained - my understanding from the other issues I read is that packages required to run various core features on Ubuntu were missing from the final app payload - and needed to be added to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Update 01/24/2018

the issue got resolved after moving to .net core 2.0